# Как сравнить даты PHP без учета часов?

Tags: php

Есть два поля с типом DATE. Нужно их сравнить только дату, не учитывая время.

например, 24.01.2023 и 24.01.2023 с разницей в 1 секунду уже не равны.

Я сравниваю так:

> $compareDate = (strtotime($openDateMysql) >
> strtotime($closedDateMysql));

Answer (score 3):

Преобразуйте в формат Y-m-d. даты в таком формате можно прекрасно сравнивать на больше-меньше или равенство

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($openDateMysql))
```